# Adobe Flash Plug-in on Chrome Warning?

Tags: google-chrome, flash

Recently, when I access Youtube, I always receive this warning message (as in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS7ru.jpg)), but I can access others websites just fine.

[image: Adobe Flash Warning]

I download, installed & update Adobe Flash several times but no help. I also tried others browsers but the warning repeats.

Anyone encounter this problem and found a way to fix this?

Thank you!

PS: I'm using Windows 10 & Google Chrome.

This is the Chrome:plugins screenshot:

[Plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJHHV.jpg)

Comment: Can you please add screenshot of chrome://plugins/?

Comment: Sure h3rat, I added the plugins screenshot.

Comment: Might be a malware or virus specifically. Did you try running antivirus scan?